# Rails where has_many.size is larger than 0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, where-clause, has-many

So this works and gets the data I need:

```
  def has_function
    services = []
    Service.find_each do |s|
      if s.functions.size > 0
        services << s
      end
    end
    return services
  end
```

However, the method returns an array, and I intend to chain it elsewhere:

```
Service.has_function.visible.includes(:layer)
undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x007faad487a970>
```

---

How can I check this and also return something that's chainable?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's in the title. It's a relation. And I think it's a totally legitimate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to do that jazz in a join, so that it's all staying in the ActiveRecord. Also... this is gonna be much faster since it's a single SQL query. Just make sure you have proper indices.

```
Service.joins(:functions).visible.includes(:layer)
```

If you wanted to check for anything beyond existence, say a count > 1; you'd have to do group/having.

```
Service.
  joins(:functions).
  select('services.*, count(functions.id) as function_count').
  group('services.id').
  having('function_count > 2')
```

Comment: I'm getting: `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "function_count" does not exist` - Do I need to specify the virtual column better?

Comment: I believe in PG you'll just want to specify it rather than use as. `having('count(functions.id) > 2')`

Answer (score -2):

Use an inner join.

```
Service.joins(:functions).visible.includes(:layer)
```

This produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT * from `services` INNER JOIN `functions` on `services`.`id`=`functions`.`service_id`
```

That inner join will eliminate services that have no functions.

Also, here's a stylistic thing that can clean up the function you wrote earlier, should you need something like that in the future:

```
def has_function
  Service.select { |s| s.functions.any? }
end
```

It's not as great on an ActiveRecord model since there are other ways to do it, but in Ruby in general, you don't need to initialize an array, push stuff onto it, and return it. `Array#select` will keep any array items for which the passed in block returns true.